# Pixelated sculptures

Tags: modeling, rendering, sculpting

I'm new to blender and I have Been trying to learn sculpting, however, I bought some excellent sculpting sets, but it's always blurry, even if I Increase the subdivision modifier
It's still blurry

Comment: Hello. Did you apply the modifier? Maybe If you  add an image that illustrates your issue, it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can only sculpt geometry that is existing for real. If you increase the details with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, this is procedural geometry, i.e. "virtual" and not yet existing geometry. It cannot be sculpted since procedural geometry can be changed anytime by changing the resolution for example. This would mean all sculpting would be lost if it could be sculpted.

To sculpt the higher detailed mesh creted by the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, you can do one of the following steps:

- Go to the modifier, hover your mouse over it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to apply it.
- At the top of the modifier, click on the dropdown menu $\lor$ and choose *Apply*.
- In the *3D Viewport* with the object selected in *Object Mode*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choose *Visual Geometry to Mesh*.

Now you have applied the modifier and generated a "real" detailed geoemetry which can be sculpted. Note that you can no longer change the subdivisions as the modifier is gone now.